# how to stop compass for converting rgba format to hex format

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, compass

I need colors in rgba format for my css file. So i wrote colors in my scss file in rgba format. When i complied all colors converted into their Hex code in css file, if their opacity is 1 else same rgba format is being used.

For example

```
SCSS File
background: rgba(61,61,61,1);

Complied Css
background: #3d3d3d;
```

If opacity is ,suppose 0.5

```
SCSS File
background: rgba(61,61,61,0.5);

Complied Css
background: rgba(61,61,61,0.5);
```

How to stop conversion for all rgba format. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: So what's wrong if it converts into hex? Anyways the value is not opaque

Comment: Nothing wrong in converting into hex code. But i need to keep all colors in same format in rgba. So that later they can be change dynamically (Requirement).

Comment: Still not getting your point. You are going to edit SASS files and not what is being compiled to. Right?

Comment: I have a form which will have textfield for all colors. when admin fill that form and save a new file will generate in css format with same name that i have mentioned earlier but with new colors. All new colors will replace old colors in new css file. that's why i need same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass will preserve the format of your color... unless it is in something other than the keyword, hex, or rgba formats.
If you want to absolute format, then you have to turn into string
For example : -
In scss variable file

$mercury-grey: #{'rgba(230, 230, 230, 1)'};

```
Input

.class {
    color: $mercury-grey;
}

Output:-
.class {
    color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 1);
}
```